# Tapping Flutter Textfield Crashes the app

Tags: android, flutter, dart, textfield

here's a video which shows my problem.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YTnu1amCYhN9CGLygAyag-LhYMn3BDiO/view?usp=sharing

Thing is, I'm developing an app in flutter and have been debugging it for several months already in a real hardware (my own phone with android 11). Suddenly, today I have experienced this error. When I tap on a textfield or textformfield, the app crushes and restarts automatically. I've researched a couple forums which suggest:

[image]

But it doesn't work for me.

I've already been several hours trying to figure this out, rebooting my pc, my phone, trying an emulator, a friend's phone instead of mine, changing the properties of the textfields... But nothing seems to work. I've read that this problem happens randomly at some android 11 devices, but have seen no solution to it (I don't even know if there exists one).

About my code, it's as simple as this:

```
                  Flexible(
                    child: FractionallySizedBox(
                      widthFactor: 0.75,
                      heightFactor: 0.75,
                      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      child: TextFormField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.person),
                          fillColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.80),
                          filled: true,
                        ),
                        onChanged: (String v) => nombre = v,
                        textInputAction: TextInputAction.go,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
```

My pubspec dependencies are:

```
firebase_core: ^1.17.1
firebase_auth: ^3.3.19
firebase_database: ^9.0.15
firebase_messaging: ^11.4.1
firebase_storage: ^10.2.17
event: ^2.0.5
mutex: ^3.0.0
chat_bubbles: ^1.3.0
clipboard: ^0.1.3
image_picker: ^0.8.5+3
shared_preferences: ^2.0.15
path_provider: ^2.0.11
xdg_directories: ^0.2.0
flutter_tts: ^3.4.0
google_speech: ^2.1.1
speech_to_text: ^5.6.0
record: ^4.1.1
gcloud: ^0.8.5
flutter_local_notifications: ^9.6.0
http: ^0.13.4
crypto: ^3.0.2
semaphore: ^0.2.1
audioplayers: ^1.0.0
spring_button: ^2.0.0
google_fonts: ^3.0.1
flutter_app_name: ^0.1.1
```

As I said, it has delivered no problems for the last months.

If anyone has an idea that may make it work again, I would be very grateful. And if want more data of my project, just ask for it. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: If it's only after starting happening today, check that your plugins are up to-date, it could be a plugin crashing the screen

Comment: I edited the post with all my dependencies in pubspec.yaml, which one do you think could be messing up with the textfields?

Comment: The most important question here is what's the error?

Comment: Wish I knew, it only shows what's on the video and console prints literally nothing (except one debug print I added, of course. Also forgot to mention it  opens like 3 separate app instances (also can be seen on the video but maybe it's not very clear).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three weeks since this problem appeared, I have at last discovered where the error was all along. It seems I had a window in the Navigator pile that was a Stateless Widget instead of a Stateful Widget, and when that happens, every time a reload happens (hot reload, textfield tapping, launching the keyboard, etc), provokes that the application restarts. It seems logical, actually, but I didn't think about that window at all, so I just popped it from the Navigator as soon as I finished with it and everything went just fine.